# Same webElement is being looped in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to loop through webelements in Selenium but the same element is being looped in python.

My HTML code is

```
<div>
  <div class="profile">
     <span class="name">One</span>
  </div>

<div class="profile">
     <span class="name">Two</span>
  </div>

<div class="profile">
     <span class="name">Three</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The python code for looping through webelement

```
profiles = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'profile')
for profile in profiles:
   print(profile.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
   print(profile.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class, "name"].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
   print("Next item \n\n")
```

Output

```
<div class="profile">
     <span class="name">One</span>
  </div>
One
Next item



<div class="profile">
     <span class="name">Two</span>
  </div>
One
Next item



<div class="profile">
     <span class="name">Three</span>
  </div>
One
Next item
```

As you can see that the div printed is unique so the loop is working, but when I try to find element inside that div, I am getting the result of first item itself (i.e "One").

I tried to make the a variable None at the begning and then assigning the profile variable into that assuiming there is some issue with the caching of variable but same result.

The output expected is

```
<div class="profile">
     <span class="name">One</span>
  </div>
One
Next item



<div class="profile">
     <span class="name">Two</span>
  </div>
Two
Next item



<div class="profile">
     <span class="name">Three</span>
  </div>
Three
Next item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **relative** XPath, like this:

```py
profiles = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'profile')
for profile in profiles:
   print(profile.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
   print(profile.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@class, "name"].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
   print("Next item \n\n")
```

All the difference is with a dot `.` making XPath to start searching inside the current node `profile`. Otherwise it searches from the top of the page.